# C# Exposing Byte Array to COM

Tags: c#, com, interop

I'm trying to create a COM dll in C# which has a byte[] property representing an image. The idea is that a colleague is writing a C++ application which will use my dll to interface with a camera.

My dll is successfully allowing his program to connect to the camera, returning various values, but the SAFEARRAY which is created seems to be unreadable (he gets a number for its length, but can't read its actual data).

1. Am I doing something stupid in attempting to pass the image out as a byte array in the manner shown below?
2. Will I need to explicitly tell Visual Studio to use a specific marshaling type, rather than allow it to choose by itself?
3. Should I be exposing a pointer to the byte array too, or will the SAFEARRAY structure take care of this.

I've only been using C# for a couple of months, and this is the first time I've written a COM dll, so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious. I've been working on the premise that question 1 isn't an issue, since a separate C# test application can reconstruct the image successfully.

**Class (excerpt):**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ResultInfo : IResult
{
    public byte[] ImageBytes
    {
        get
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            this.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] returnBytes = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close();
            return returnBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface (excerpt):**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IResult
{
    [DispId(5)]
    byte[] ImageBytes { get; }
}
```

**EDIT:** This is the output from the C++ side of things:

> When I try to access the SAFEARRAY using  HRESULT hr =
>   SafeArrayAccessData (image, &data) ; The hr returned is E_UNEXPECTED -
>   the documentation for SafeArrayAccessData says that this is "The safe
>   array could not be locked"

Comment: to be blunt, yes you are doing something stupid! ;-) the .NET runtime reserves the right to move data about (including the byte[] declared in you code - C++ will be expecting the data to be in a fixed memory location. You need to use some of the Interop classes to help you here - also use the "fixed" keyword to stop the garbage collector moving the data about

Comment: Thanks Jimmy! I'd read that this was possible, but it obviously didn't sink in... Out of interest, why isn't this the case for other variables?

Comment: the other variables (e.g. the length) will be copied during the marshalling process - therefore the correct data will make its way to the C++. However, the byte[] is a reference to data, and you'll have to use the Interop marshalling classes to help you to move that up to the C++ - you'll also have to worry about releasing the byte array (possibly via another call to your COM server). I would recommend, unless you have a requirement to use COM, perhaps just using P/Invoke.